# Marionette - not able to append to regions

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to append a view in to a region, but i am getting an error saying:

```
undefined is not a function
```

here is my template:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script id="my-layout" type="text/html">
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</script>
<script id="menuTemp" type="text/template">
    <p>I am from Menu</p>

</script>
```

here is my script:

```
var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template($('#menuTemp').html()),
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
       this.$el.html(this.template);
       return this;
    }
});

container = new Backbone.Marionette.Region({
  el: "#container"
});

MyLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#my-layout",

  regions: {
    menu: "#menu",
    content: "#content"
  }
});

// Show the "layout" in the "container" region
layout = new MyLayout();
container.show(layout);

layout.menu.show(new MenuView().render().el); //not working
```

[Here is Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hL2fqyyj/2/)

Any one help me to fix the issue please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use a marionette view not a backbone view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your last line:

```
layout.menu.show(new MenuView().render().el)
```

Marionette automagically takes care of rendering the view. So you just need to call:

```
layout.menu.show(new MenuView())
```

And it'll work just great.